# Sorting numpy matrix results in value error

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, matrix, valueerror

I created a numpy matrix called `my_stocks` with two columns:

- column 0 is made by specific objects that I defined
- column 1 is made of integers

I try to sort it by column 1, but this causes ValueError: `np.sort(my_stocks)`

The full method:

```
def sort_stocks(self):
    my_stocks = np.empty(2)
    for data in self.datas:
        if data.buflen() > self.p.period:
            new_stock=[data,get_slope(self,data)]
            my_stocks = np.vstack([my_stocks,new_stock])
    self.stocks = np.sort(my_stocks)
```

It doesn't cause problems if instead of sorting the matrix, I print it. A print example is below:

```
 [<backtrader.feeds.yahoo.YahooFinanceData object at 0x124ec2eb0>
  1.1081551020408162]
 [<backtrader.feeds.yahoo.YahooFinanceData object at 0x124ec2190>
  0.20202275819418677]
 [<backtrader.feeds.yahoo.YahooFinanceData object at 0x124eda610>
  0.08357118119975258]
 [<backtrader.feeds.yahoo.YahooFinanceData object at 0x124ecc400>
  0.5487027829313539]]
```

Comment: This looks like a mistaken translation of a list loop to numpy!  Did you pay attention to what `empty` does, and how it appears in the result.  Repeated `vstack` is slower than list append.  You didn't specify sorting on column 1 in any way.  The python `list.sort` does take a `key` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the method was sorting my matrix by raw and not by column.

This works even if it looks rather counterintuitive:

`my_stocks[my_stocks[:, 1].argsort()]`

Comment: Without `axis` `np.sort` flattens the array (did you read the docs?).  You didn't show the `ValueError`, but I suspect it had to do with ordering those 'feeds' objects.